# convert a datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a datatable like this

```
  X,Y,Z
  0,0,A
  0,2,B
  0,0,C
  1,0,A
  1,0,C
  2,2,A
  2,2,B
  2,0,C
  3,2,B
  3,1,C
  4,3,A
  4,0,B
  4,1,C
  5,3,A
  5,2,B
  5,0,C
```

and I want to convert it to something like this:

```
  X,A,B,C
  0,0,2,0
  1,0, ,0
  2,2,2,0
  3, ,2,1
  4,3,0,1
  5,3,2,0
```

I tried with dataset and linq but not I wasn't lucky.

My code for linq:

```
    Dim q = (From c In dt _
          Select c("Z") Distinct) 'I found out which categories I have in Z column (my example :A,B,C)
     Dim ldt(q.Count) As DataTable

     For i = 0 To q.Count - 1
        Dim sfil As String = q(i).ToString
        Dim r = (From c In dt _
        Select c Where c("Z") = sfil)
        ldt(i) = r.CopyToDataTable
     Next
```

So now I have 3 tables (ldt(0) with values for A, ldt(1) with values for B, ldt(2) with values for C)
and I was thinking to do something like leftJoin but anything that I tried is fail.
Any solution or even a better idea?

Thanks

So a new example it would be:
I have this table:

```
 id,Price,Item
  0,0,Laptop
  0,2,Tablet
  0,0,Cellphone
  1,0,Laptop
  1,0,Tablet
  2,2,Laptop
  2,2,Cellphone
  2,0,Tablet
  3,2,Cellphone
  3,1,Tablet
  4,3,Laptop
  4,0,Cellphone
  4,1,Tablet
  5,3,Laptop
  5,2,Cellphone
  5,0,Tablet
```

and I would like to convert it to this:

```
  X,Laptop,Tablet,Cellphone
  0,0,2,0
  1,0, ,0
  2,2,2,0
  3, ,2,1
  4,3,0,1
  5,3,2,0
```

The values for each of the columns Laptop, Tablet, Cellphone are the Y values from the first table.

I hope it make more sense now.

Comment: I can't work out how you're getting from the starting table to the finishing table.  What is the relation between the two?

Comment: I see that you want to group by x, but i have no plan what A,B,Z are and what happens to y. Can you explain it less puzzling ? By the way, it would be much better to see the sample data as code (f.e. `table.Rows.Add(0,0,"A")`). Then we could test it immediately.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake the last column in second datatable is C.
So the first datatable is coming from database.
I want to convert first dataset to the second like that:
1.Find the different values for Z column of first datatable(In my case A,B,C)
2. So in second datatable it will have the distinct values X from first datatable and columns A,B,C with the corresponding values Y for X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can create a DataTable with column names corresponding to the item names.  Then you group the previous DataTable by `id` and use each grouping to populate a row.  Forgive me if I get anything wrong.  I don't work with VB or DataTables that much.

```
Dim itemNames = (From c In dt _
                 Select c("Item") Distinct)

Dim newDt as DataTable = new DataTable()
Dim idColumn As DataColumn = new DataColumn()
idColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
idColumn.ColumnName = "id"
idColumn.ReadOnly = True
idColumn.Unique = True 

newDt.Columns.Add(idColumn)

For Each itemName As String In itemNames
    Dim column As DataColumn = new DataColumn()
    column.DataType = GetType(Nullable(Of Integer))
    column.ColumnName = itemName
    column.ReadOnly = True
    column.Unique = False
    newDt.Columns.Add(column)
Next

Dim groupingById = From row in dt
                   Group By Id = row("id")
                   Into RowsForId = Group

For Each grouping In groupingById
    Dim row as DataRow = newDt.NewRow()
    row("id") = grouping.Id
    For Each rowForId in grouping.RowsForId
        row(rowForId("Item")) = rowForId("Price")
    Next
    newDt.Rows.Add(row)
Next
```

Comment: @ GN_Habouf I'm glad it worked!  Helping people feels great sometimes :D